# Excel: Skip loop if cell returns #N/A Error

Tags: excel, vba, loops, error-handling

I wrote below script but get hung up on this part of the code:

```
If TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F61").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then GoTo Skip Else GoTo Continue
```

What I'm trying to do: if the value of the cell returns #N/A as part of a function I would like to move to next loop. Any recommendation on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for solutions. Also always open to recommendations on how to better structure this code, as I'm still a beginner.

```
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Dim TargetWb As Workbook
    Dim S_Deal As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'SourceWb - Workbook were data is copied from
    'TargetWb - Workbook were data is copied to and links are stored
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set TargetWb = ThisWorkbook
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expenses").Range("S4").Value
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    For i = 1 To 6
   
 If TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F61").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then GoTo Skip Else GoTo Continue
    
Continue:

    Set S_Deal = TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Cells(11, 5 + i)
    SourceWb.ActiveSheet.Range("OPEX_Control").Value = S_Deal.Value
    
    
    TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F12:F15").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = SourceWb.ActiveSheet.Range("P9:P12").Value
    TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F18:F21").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = SourceWb.ActiveSheet.Range("o14:o17").Value
    TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F23:F26").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = SourceWb.ActiveSheet.Range("o19:o22").Value
    TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F29").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = SourceWb.ActiveSheet.Range("o25").Value
    
Skip:
    
    Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `GoTo Skip` should be enough. ` Else GoTo Continue` should be deleted and the label ` Continue:`, too. Anyhow, the code goes to the next row if not going to `Skip` label. Then, what "get hung up" does mean? Didn't it return an error? If yes, what error?

Comment: In terms of making the code more compact and neat, please declare a variable `Dim shEx As Worksheet` and set it as `Set shEx = TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses")`. Then, replace all `TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses")` with `shEx`.

Comment: @FaneDuru and the same with `SourceWb.ActiveSheet`

Comment: Instead of `filePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expenses").Range("S4").Value`. You could declare the filepath as a constant inside the code module like `Const filePath as String = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\"`. That way you don't have to dedicate sheet space for something the users don't need to see. Plus it protects it from being accidentally changed or deleted by a user.

Comment: @Toddleson: If he knows the sheet name, yes. But if the situation involves different sheets and processing the active one, it cannot be done. Anyhow, opening the workbook by code it is the active one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether the excel function return #N/A in vba, you can use the following code:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(intRow, x)) Then
```

Since what you want is the execute a code unless the the wb.function is not #N/A, by re-arrange your If VBA code should be able to achieve your desired outcome.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(TargetWb.Sheets("Expenses").Range("F61")) = false then
{your code}
end if

next i
```

So when the wb function return #N/A, it will not execute the code in between and go to next loop

Comment: If it is similar, I don't get why he is stuck to achieve his outcome, then maybe his problem is another issue then. Thanks for explanation also.